# Query too slow due to use of cursors

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to remove cursor from stored procedure.

```
 Declare cur_Acc_Map cursor local for   

 Select Group_No from Account_Group   
 Where Company_No in (0,@Company_No) and Group_No <> 14  
 and Parent_Group_No = @Parent_Id  
 order by Group_Name  


 open cur_Acc_Map  
 fetch next from cur_Acc_Map into @Group_No  
 while @@fetch_status <> -1  
  begin  
     exec SP_Account_Map_Process @Company_No, @UserName, @HostName, @Sequence,           @Group_No, @Level_Id,@Acc_year,@From_date,@To_date,@DispMode  
     fetch next from cur_Acc_Map into @Group_No  
  End  
  close cur_Acc_Map  
 deallocate cur_Acc_Map
```

How to avaid cursors in this case .

Exucution time of this query is 7 seconds, which is too much, sometimes it takes even more. How to effeciently make use of joins here or should I manually iterate through fetched records one by one, will that help

Full procedure is as below:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_Account_Map_Process]  
@Company_No int,  
@UserName varchar(50),  
@HostName varchar(50),  
@Sequence int,  
@Parent_Id int = 0,  
@Level_Id int = 0,  
@Acc_year int=0,  
   @From_date datetime= null,  
   @To_date datetime =null,  
   @DispMode int=0  
   As  
   Begin  

   if @Level_Id = 0  
    Begin  
  Set @Parent_Id = 0   
 End  

   Set @Level_Id = @Level_Id + 1  

   Declare @Group_No int, @SrNo int  

   Set @SrNo = isnull((select MAX(Num03) from Rpt_Temp where UserName =   @UserName and HostName = @HostName and ReportName = 'ACC_MAP'),0) + 1  
 print @SrNo  



 insert into Rpt_Temp (UserName , HostName, ReportName,    
  Num01 , Num02 , Num03, Num04,Num05, Num06, Num07, Num08,  
  Str01,Str02 )  
  select @UserName, @HostName, 'ACC_MAP',   
  @Company_No, @Sequence, @SrNo, @Level_Id-1, @Parent_Id, Parent_Group_No, 0, 1,   
  Group_Name,  
  Case when Account_Group.is_fixed='T' then   
   LTRIM(RTRIM(cast(@Company_No as varchar(10)) + '.' +  Account_Group.Tree_ID))   
   else    
   LTRIM(RTRIM(Account_Group.Tree_ID))   
  end    
   from Account_Group where Group_No = @Parent_Id  


 Declare cur_Acc_Map cursor local for   

 Select Group_No from Account_Group   
 Where Company_No in (0,@Company_No) and Group_No <> 14  
 and Parent_Group_No = @Parent_Id  
 order by Group_Name  


  open cur_Acc_Map  
  fetch next from cur_Acc_Map into @Group_No  
  while @@fetch_status <> -1  
  begin  
  exec SP_Account_Map_Process @Company_No, @UserName, @HostName, @Sequence,    @Group_No, @Level_Id,@Acc_year,@From_date,@To_date,@DispMode  
  fetch next from cur_Acc_Map into @Group_No  
 End  
 close cur_Acc_Map  
 deallocate cur_Acc_Map  

  insert into Rpt_Temp (UserName , HostName, ReportName,    
   Num01 , Num02 , Num03, Num04,Num05, Num06, Num07, Num08,  
   Str01,str02)  
  select @UserName, @HostName, 'ACC_MAP',   
   @Company_No, @Sequence, @SrNo, @Level_Id, 0, Parent_Group_No, Account_No, 0,   
  Account_Name,Tree_ID   
 from Account Where Company_No = @Company_No and Parent_Group_No =    @Parent_Id  

End
```

Comment: You can't since you're calling an SP inside the cursor. You may want to post the content of `SP_Account_Map_Process`. Maybe you can eliminate individual calls to it.

Comment: This is called within itself, I mean this is `SP_Account_Map_Process`

Comment: I don't understand, so it's calling itself? As a sidenote, avoid prefixing your stored procs with `sp_`. Read this for more info: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I updated question, i posted complete procedure

Comment: please have a look now @wewesthemenace . this procedure has already been created by other previous employee, so i cant change naming convention